# Even though I assign the same version of the project to Nexus every time it is deployed, it does not delete the previous one

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

Even though I assign the same version of the project to Nexus every time it is deployed, it does not completely delete the previous one. disk constantly filling up

I upload my projects to Nexus with kaniko. When I throw in my same version projects, it does not delete the previous images that I have not used, that is, it does not overwrite them.

```
first    I pushed: authentication:0.0.1 Disk Usage: 14.1 GB 
second   I pushed: authentication:0.0.1 Disk Usage: 14.7 GB
third    I pushed: authentication:0.0.1 Disk Usage: 15.3 GB
```

**I selected Allow redeploy for the Deploy policy for the repository on Nexus.**
After then
**I run “Compact blob store”**

But **there is still a difference of 360 mb.**

> Disk Usage: 14.9 GB

The disk keeps filling up. What I expect is for it to overwrite automatically. How can I get it to overwrite automatically on Nexus?

[image]